# How to create pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I have a pipeline job created in Jenkins and I need to create a pipeline script that displays the failure and unstable builds in developement stage. What are the steps to create this in Jenkins 2.0 or Is there any sample pipeline script

Answer (score 1):

For start just follow steps from [tutorial](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/), ex

```
node { 
    git url: 'https://github.com/joe_user/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git' 
    def mvnHome = tool 'M3' 
    sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -B verify"
}
```

And you can change build status using `currentBuild.result` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is it possible to have the pipeline with the projects running on Subversion and ANT

Comment: Subversion is supported, and Ant could be used similarly like Maven is, with `sh` step.